# How to speed up simple OCR task?

Tags: python, image-processing, optimization, ocr, tesseract

I got script that plays a simple math game: given a math equation (eg: 1 + 1 = 3), tap the True or False button in a progressively shorter limited amount of time.

I use:

- PIL for screen capturing and preprocessing (inverting)
- (Py)Tesseract for OCR

Pseudocode:

```
while True:
  capture_and_invert_image_with_PIL() # ~0.065+ sec
  read_image_with_pytesseract()       # ~0.100+ sec
  check_math_expression()             # ~0      sec
  click_button()                      # ~0.035+ sec
  wait_for_next_equation()
                                # total ~0.200+ sec
```

I have trained a custom font language to decrease the OCR process to 0.1 sec from ~0.45 sec with the default `eng.traineddata` and ~0.25 sec with the fast version.

Solutions I think could work but haven't found any way to do them:

- Run Python at 100% CPU (most Google results say multithreading which is impossible for this task)
- Run Tesseract at 100% CPU
- Keep Tesseract running (so no loading to memory everytime, I guess)

Comment: where is the ecuation from? if its from a website you could get the text directly instead of treating it as image, unless the equation is an image there too. Also why click_button is taking so long?

Comment: @juvian It's from an Android app running on BlueStacks. The function for clicking is from [CodeBullet](https://github.com/Code-Bullet/Piano-Tiles/blob/master/directKeys.py). It varies a lot, ranging from 5 to 50 ms, averaging around 35 ms.

Comment: Maybe you can try to limit the area of the image you need to capture to where the equation should be instead of full screen

Comment: Already did. I'm just looking for ways to realize the solutions I propose.